# Как реализовать обмен ip-адресами в c#

Tags: c#, база-данных

Есть программа для работы с БД в локальной сети среди нескольких компьютеров(5-7).
Один из компьютеров - воображаемый сервер на котором хранится БД.
Как реализовать функцию рассылки всем программам на других компьютерах этого ip-адреса, для подключения к БД.
Или нужен другой подход?

Answer (score 2):

То что вы описали больше всего похоже на Р2Р-облако - когда один из компов объявляет себя раздающим услугу, а все остальные подключающиеся к сети юзают эту его услугу и рассказывают окружающим)

Здача интересная, но гемморойная и на 5-10 компов - не нужная.

А в случае с вами - БД вероятнее всего находится на одном компе, и никуда с него не девается. Поэтому стоит просто положить конфиг-файл на каждый клиент, чтоб они знали, где искать свой сервер.

Comment: нет, в программу включена функция резервного копирования БД на другой компьютер.
статическое определение ip не подходит.

Comment: а как вы оцените возможность отправки этого Ip по tcp/ip всем компьютерам пингующимся?(только сам не знаю как их найти).

Comment: Самое базовое решение:

- прога запускается. Открывает на прослушку ТСР(UDP)-порт. И тут же проходится по всей своей подсети запросами на этот же порт.
- если успешный коннект, то прога называет себя (по ИП-ли, рендомно или как-то так), и получает в ответ от другого компа его данные и текущую топологию (кто сервер, кто резерв и т.п.). Они обе у себя в массиве отмечают друг друга.
- и так пока не опросит всех. Если никто не ответил, то считает главной себя.
- сеть периодически опрашивает всех или соседей, на предмет не пропал ли никто.

Comment: На TCP будет медленнее, но надежнее. На UDP - быстро, но без гарантий.

Так как речь идет о бакапах, я бы ещё рекомендовал подумать об авторизации пиров сети.

Answer (score 1):

Для ваших задач должен подойти udp. Вот [пример](http://www.interestprograms.ru/sources/csharp/ishodnik-otpravki-soobscheniy-po-seti-udp-p1.html) про UDP в С#.

Видится такое решение. Клиент, посылает udp сообщение "кто нынче сервак?" и нынешний сервер ответит тоже udp сообщением, мол, "я, мой ip такой".

Comment: Не столько UDP, сколько именно бродкаст или, лучше, мультикаст.

Comment: @drdaeman да, направление для гугленния задано )

Comment: Да, примерно так. Только лучше еще иметь локальный файл с адресом сервера. Сначала пытаетесь сделать коннект по адресу из файла. Если не получилось - broadcast запрос(ы), потом (в случае успеха) обновление файла.

Дело в том, что broadcast "грузят" сетку и админы сети смотрят на такие протоколы handshaking-а косо. Тут лучше не сыпать запросы очень часто.

В таком алгоритме сервер при запуске должен проверять, что он единственный (используя аналогичный протокол поиска). Если он удачно стартовал, то начинает (плюс к основной работе) слушать UDP запросы и отвечать своим адресом.

--

Успехов.